# Returning function as parameter with closures

Tags: javascript, scope, closures

```
function inputCheck(input) {
  if (input.name==="email") {
    console.log("email")
    return isValidEmail
  } else if (input.name==="password") {
    return isValidPassword
    console.log("pass")
  } else if (input.name==="userName") {
    return isValidUserName
    console.log("user")
  }
}


function isValidEmail (email) {
  return /^[^@]+[@][^@.]+\.[a-z]+$/.test(email)
}

function isValidPassword(pass) {
  return /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{8,}$/.test(pass)
}

function isValidUserName(user) {
  return /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([_ -]?[a-zA-Z0-9])*$/.test(user)
}


function validation(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  inputs.forEach(input=> createListener(inputCheck(input)))
}



function createListener(validator) {
  return (e)=> {
    const inputValue=e.target.value;
    const valid=validator(inputValue)
    console.log(valid)
  }
}
```

I'm trying to create form validation using closures. I am trying to make my code as efficient as possible.

I want to loop over each input element (without selecting each individually), and apply an event listener to each one. The inputCheck function would return a validator function depending on the name attribute of each input, and the createListener function takes the value returned by inputCheck, which would be a specific type of validator, and then for testing purposes, console.log true or false.

So far, the only if branch that works in the inputCheck function is the first one associated with name attribute email. The other if branches won't work if I type values into other input elements and submit the form.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong and how to improve my code?

I'm new to closures so I understand that this issue might seem relatively simple to most of you.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? The `console.log` is placed after the `return` for both password and userName. Because of this, the `console.log` will not be executed, since a `return` immediately terminates the function, so you won't *see* the log `"pass"` or `"user"` but you will get the correct validator function returned.

Comment: why don't you use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation ?

Answer (score 0):

I can observe two things:

First, just like @VLAZ pointed out, two console.log in inputCheck are actually not executed since they are placed after return.

Second, `createListener` and `validation` are not quite right. `createListener` returns a function with one argument. `validation` forEach doesn't log anything because `createListener` returns a function, no function execution here.

There is another problem with the argument `e` of `createListener`. It seems like you treat it as an event, but based on your implementation, there is only one event, that is form submit event. So, I'd suggest to modify these two functions a little bit:

```js
function validation(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  inputs.forEach(input=> createListener(inputCheck(input))(input))
}



function createListener(validator) {
  return (e)=> {
    const inputValue=e.value;
    const valid=validator(inputValue)
    console.log(valid)
  }
}
```

Then, the console prints out true or false based on the input value of each input field.
Please check whether the output is your intension or not https://jsfiddle.net/jqgbefhw/